# Create excel from html table

Tags: javascript, excel

I wan't to grab a HTML table and save it as an excel-file.

I found this article:
https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/

Easy coding:

```
<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tblData', 'members-data')">Export Table Data To Excel File</button>

function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
  var downloadLink;
  var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
  var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

  // Specify file name
  filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

  // Create download link element
  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
        type: dataType
    });
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
  }else{
    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

    // Setting the file name
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    
    //triggering the function
    downloadLink.click();
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that when i open the file in Google spreadsheet i see the html code. Of corse i want it to be a excel sheet without html code. What is the problem?

[image]

There is a comment:

```
//I had to encode # signs as well before the script would work with any non-Safari browser:
var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, ‘%20’).replace(/#/g, ‘%23’);
```

This wont solve the html problem.

Comment: Should that not be `excel_data.xlsx`

Comment: `Google Sheets` != `Microsoft Excel`. `Microsoft Excel` will tolerate `HTML` code given as `*.xls` and converts this into cells in a worksheet. `Google Sheets` will not do so.

Comment: @AxelRichter true. It works in Excel but not in google sheets. I will search for a script that work for both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code actually works with Excel.

I was testing in Google Sheet, thats why it didn't work.